# How does Mathematica connect to Bluetooth 4.0 device and analyze sampled data?

Tags: input-devices, datadrop

How does Mathematica connect to heart rate device via Bluetooth 4.0 and analyze the sampled data? The FindDevices command has tried but the device cannot found. Are there any things to be aware or other methods?

---

This question was [cross-posted to Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1454516).

Comment: Please, add further information about the device. Model and library available?. Does the device has a Serial port? How do you communicate with the computer?